# A column will save null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In a php form, I wanted the user put his gender with a select tag

In the file Controller, I want check the field data

My form codes:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', getOption('app_name') . ' - register')
@section('content')
    <style>
        /* already defined in bootstrap4 */
        .text-xs-center {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .g-recaptcha {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 pull-center"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-center">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Register</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="name"
                                       type="text"
                                       class="form-control login-field"
                                       placeholder="@lang('forms.name')"
                                       name="name"
                                       value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="email"
                                       type="email"
                                       class="form-control login-field"
                                       placeholder="@lang('forms.email')"
                                       name="email"
                                       value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="phone"
                                       type="tel"
                                       class="form-control login-field"
                                       placeholder="شماره موبایل"
                                       name="phone"
                                       value="{{ old('phone') }}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                                <span class="help-block" style="color:red">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="password"
                                       type="password"
                                       class="form-control login-field"
                                       placeholder="@lang('forms.password')"
                                       name="password">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="password-confirm"
                                       type="password"
                                       class="form-control login-field"
                                       name="password_confirmation"
                                       placeholder="@lang('forms.confirm_password')" >
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <select name="gender"
                                        id="gender"
                                        class="form-control login-field"
                                        style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;font-size:12px">
                                    <option value="">Select your gender</option>
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('gender'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('gender') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="text-xs-center">
                                {!! Captcha::display() !!}
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                @lang('buttons.register')
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
@push('scripts')
    {!! Captcha::script() !!}
@endpush
```

The Controller codes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\PaymentMethod;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Arcanedev\NoCaptcha\Rules\CaptchaRule;
use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
        config(["no-captcha.sitekey" => getOption('recaptcha_public_key')]);
        config(["no-captcha.secret" => getOption('recaptcha_private_key')]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new CaptchaRule],
        ],[
            'email.regex' => "Your email isn't a valid email",
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if ( $data['gender'] == 'female'){
            $gender = $data['gender'];
        }else{
            $gender = 'male';
        }

        return User::create([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'gender' => $gender,
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }


    public function finish($data){
        $user = $this->create($data);

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

But now, when user select test option, the gender will save null!
But I said save male in this controller if the field value isn't female
Where this code is false?

Comment: Does this code actually works ? You should get some sort of error in the create fuinction: `if ( $data['gender'] == 'female')){` There's 1 opening `(` but 2 closings `)`

Comment: In my main code this is correct but when I edited here, I edited incorrectly, anyway my main code is: `if ($data['gender'] == 'female'){
            $gender = $data['gender'];
        }else{
            $gender = 'male';
        }`

Comment: Show us what the $data array looks like entering the create function. There most likely is an assumption being made somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra ) in the if statement where you assign $gender.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain one more?

Comment: I was referring exactly what @Djip was stating. Why the down vote? Given the code you presented that was a pretty obvious issue.

Answer (score -1):

*Try this code in your controller :*

```
$gender = 'male';
if ( $data['gender'] == 'female'){
    $gender = $data['gender'];
}
```